# Sampling Highly Imbalanced Large Dataset

Tags: class-imbalance, binary-classification

I am working on a model which will run monthly on 8M users. I've snapshot-wise data in training set, eg:

1. Jan, 21 Snapshot : 8M Total : 233 Positives Rest Negative
2. Feb, 21 Snapshot : 8M Total : 599 Positives Rest Negative
3. March, 21 Snapshot : 8M Total : 600 Positives Rest Negative
4. April, 21 Snapshot : 8M Total : 750 Positives Rest Negative

similarly till March, 2022

I'm keeping March, 2022 as test set, which has 2000 positive labels and rest negative out of 8M.

I can't take all 8M rows from each snapshot in the training set, how should I sample my data ? Currently, I am taking all rows with positive class, and only 300K negative class rows from each snapshot. This makes training set distribution : 420K negative class samples and 8K positive class samples.

Am I sampling right ? Which CV technique will be right and what metric should be used to select best model ?

Comment: Need more information about the how the training and test datasets were sampled..  Are the training and test data sets balanced, or are they unbalanced in terms of the predictors?

Comment: 8M is the total population, I'm asking how should I sample w.r.t the target which is highly imbalanced

Comment: without knowing how the population is stratified over the variables, simple random sampling with yield the most unbiased results